# sails policies - use variables

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm starting to get quite a few sails policies that look like this:

```
...
'MyController':{
    'some': ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled'],
    'action': ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled'],
    'here': ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled', 'extra'],
},
....
```

The problem is repetition. I would like to have a shortcut such as "userIsAuthenticated".

I can declare a variable

```
var userIsAuthenticated = ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled'];
....

'MyController':{
    'some': userIsAuthenticated,
    'action': userIsAuthenticated,
    'here': Array.concat(userIsAuthenticated, ['extra'],
},
```

My problem is the here action. I think the syntax is hard to read and error prone.

I tried writing:

```
'MyController':{
    'some': userIsAuthenticated,
    'action': userIsAuthenticated,
    'here': [userIsAuthenticated, 'extra'],
},
```

Which looks beautiful. And it might have worked. Although I Understand that I get one array with two items and the first item being an array with 3 items.

So, question is. Is it safe to declare policies like that in Sails or not. I cannot find any mention of that syntax in the manual (http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies) . Is there perhaps some other approach?

Answer (score 2):

> So, question is. Is it safe to declare policies like that in Sails or
>   not. I cannot find any mention of that syntax in the manual
>   (http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies) . Is there
>   perhaps some other approach?

By using

```
var userIsAuthenticated = ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled'];
....

'MyController':{
    'some': userIsAuthenticated,
    'action': userIsAuthenticated,
    'here': Array.concat(userIsAuthenticated, ['extra'],
},
```

or

```
'MyController':{
    'some': userIsAuthenticated,
    'action': userIsAuthenticated,
    'here': [userIsAuthenticated, 'extra'],
},
```

you win nothing. You make it even harder to understand for other developers since the documentation is describing it this way

```
...
'MyController':{
    'some': ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled'],
    'action': ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled'],
    'here': ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled', 'extra'],
},
....
```

But I know how you feel. So what you can do is to define policies at model or controller level:

```
module.exports.policies = {
    '*': true,
    MyModel: ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled'], // model level
    MyController: { // controller level    
        '*': ['runPassport', 'isLoggedIn', 'ensureTotpOkIfEnabled'],
        fooAction: 'extra'
    }
};
```

The the problem is however that the `fooAction` does not inherit the policy of `*` which is weird. As a result only the `extra` policy will be called for the `fooAction`. So there is no real solution to your problem. You can create a proposal here https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues.